# Is it possible to encapsulate multiple .net assembiles to offer a single public interface?

Tags: .net, encapsulation, .net-assembly, facade

I've created a component in .NET which is intented to be used in multiple .NET solutions in other companies or development teams.

My component consists of multiple DLLs.  Roughly, it has:

- A **core** DLL that can make lots of operations, and
- A **facade** DLL that offers just a small subset of those operations, so that component can be customized for different customers or integrations.

The thing is that I don't want anybody to be able to access the **core** methods, but only the **facade** ones.  This way I would ensure that nobody tries to cheat by calling **core** methods directly, instead of the **facade** methods.

Is it possible to achieve that?  Is there any pattern or good practice in order to achieve such encapsulation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the access modifiers of the **core** types `internal` and utilise the [`InternalsVisibleToAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) to share `internal` implementations across your own assemblies. This attribute would allow your **facade** DLL to get access to **core** internals.

This won't stop the determined person from using reflection, however. What it does it make it non-trivial to get access, which is usually enough to direct most people across to the publicly exposed types.

Also, a lack of documentation on the internal stuff when publishing the assemblies will dissuade people - coupled with very good documentation for the public types.

It would be prudent to always look at how people are trying to use your assemblies. There may be types in **core** that people favour heavily because they are useful or have a use you had not considered - be prepared to expose these through the **facade** to meet consumer demand.

Comment: +1, exactly what I was going to suggest. The interesting question is, however: assume the core is already coded, with hundreds or more classes. How can we achieve the same goal without changing the visibility of every class in the core one-by-one?

Comment: @DocBrown Indeed that is an interesting question. I don't know of any standard way to tackle this, though I'd imagine it would be something to with post-processing the assembly after it has been produced. Global "find and replace" public to internal for the project and crossed-fingers I would say.

Comment: Excellent answer and explanation and interesting comments, +1 for both, and accepted answer.

Comment: I have added using `StrongNameIdentityPermissionAttribute` to my answer. I have not used this personally, but it seems like it is what you need.

Comment: @row1 That may not work as intended, I have commented on your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can change all your core *public* methods/members/etc to *internal* and then use [InternalsVisibleToAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) to make all the internal items visible to the façade.

<s>An alternative would be to use the [StrongNameIdentityPermissionAttribute](http://www.morganskinner.com/Articles/StrongNameIdentityPermission/) which will:</s>

> Quarantee that a caller (either the immediate caller or one somewhere
>   up the call chain) has been signed with a particular strong name.
>    (This no longer works as intended)

Comment: That attribute may not work as intended, there is a nice remark in the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.strongnameidentitypermissionattribute.aspx) docs about it no longer being used in .NET 4 and having some different behaviour in .NET 2.